# angularjs angular hybrid application very slow

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular6, angular-hybrid, angularjs-gridster

i am just using an angular component library called [gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster) in my large angularjs application. for that i made my app hybrid, as in future we are planning to upgrade our application to be on completely on angular. i am using 1.4.3 angularjs and 6.0 angular version.

after making my application it has become very slow.

Any suggestion please.

most of the module and directives is angularjs, i have followed standard approach of upgrade provided in angular documentation. downgraded angular gridster component.

Comment: I had similar issues  on my project.
Do you use `UpgradeModule` or `DowngradeModule` to bootstrap hybrid app?

Comment: i used DowngradeModule